# jQuery effects: where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've scoured the internet for solutions, but I have gotten utterly stuck. Basically, I'm wanting three buttons equally sized and horizontal that reveal and hide three different content sections.

I had the buttons, by using a `span + h3` styled with CSS, displayed in a horizontal row using inline-block; but, then the CSS broke when i added the accordion function and also the accordion makes it a vertical stack anyway.

1) Am I right in thinking it should've been a blind effect rather than accordion? Can anyone show me how to get it to work as I'm wanting?

2) Why is my CSS broken even after I took the accordion back out? I'm assuming I've cut something out or added something whilst trying to get it right and that has caused it to stop?

3) I also had the accordion functioning so that it automatically closed any open content on the next click. I'm assuming I've broken this whilst messing about too - but again I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

HTML

#### title 1

```
    <section>
        <p>one</p>
     </section>
     <h5>Or</h5>
 <span class="button"><h3>title 2</h3></span>

 <section>
    <p>two</p>
 </section>
     <h5>Or</h5>
  <span class="button"><h3>title 3</h3></span>

<section>
      <p>three</p>
 </section>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
div#container span.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width:29%;
    background-color:red;
}
div#container span.block h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
div#container section {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
    /* Initially hide all 'section' content */
    var allPanels = $('#container > section').hide();

    /* on block-btn/ h3 click - use slide toggle effect to hide/ show content */
    $('#container > span.button > h3').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle()
            .siblings('.hide').slideUp();
         return false;
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#container .hide').slideUp();
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

My Accordion problem - http://jsfiddle.net/SparrowWoods/2fsagge1/

Comment: Just btw, jquery ui has a ready made accordion.

Comment: Also, you're targeting span.block instead of span.button.

Comment: Sorry, yes I've changed the names to make the example easier - must have missed one. I've got a working accordion function minus the fact I've somehow broken it from disappearing after the next items been clicked. But I'm wanting my buttons to sit horizontally and then reveal the page content below the buttons, and swap out accordingly?

Comment: sorry, no sooner did i post this i got a new job and things went crazy!! thank you for your responses, it wasnt the standard accordion i was after, but i managed to build my own version using various show/hides as you suggested so i will accept your answer thankyou. Im finding embedding functions within functions seems to break things, i think maybe i should be looking at plugins for these situations? but it seems an unnecessarily bulky solution and not always good enough on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own Accordion based on [THIS](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/) by trying something to the tune of this:

```
(function ($) {
    /* Initially hide all 'section' content */
    /*var allPanels = $('#container > section').hide();

     on block-btn/ h3 click - use slide toggle effect to hide/ show content */
    /*$('#container > span.button > h3').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle()
            .siblings('.hide').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#container .hide').slideUp();
    });*/

    $(".button").click(function(){
          $('.subDiv').slideUp("slow");
          $(this).next('.subDiv').slideDown("slow");
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Here, you can just leverage JQuery's slideUp and slideDown functions along with nested `<ul>` and `<li>` or `<div>` tags in conjunction with JQuery UI Library.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> <span class="button"><h3>title 1</h3></span>
<div class="subDiv">
    <section>
        <p>one</p>
    </section>
    </div>
     <h5>Or</h5>
 <div class="button"><h3>title 2</h3></div>
<div class="subDiv">
    <section>
        <p>two</p>
    </section>
    </div>
     <h5>Or</h5>
 <div class="button"><h3>title 3</h3></div>
<div class="subDiv">
    <section>
        <p>three</p>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it in your Fiddle implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're content using jquery uis readymade accordion: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/2fsagge1/1/)

```
<div id="accordion"> 
    <h3>title 1</h3>

    <section>
        <p>one</p>
    </section>

 <h3>title 2</h3>

    <section>
        <p>two</p>
    </section>

    <h3>title 3</h3>

    <section>
        <p>three</p>
    </section>
</div>

$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```